# C# array sort explanation

Tags: c#, sorting

Can someone please explain how the for loops works here after iterating through all indexes. I'm not understanding how the for loops are working again and again until all the numbers are sorted.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[] {9,1,6,3,7,2,4};
        int temp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length;j++)
            {
                if(arr[i]>arr[j])
                {
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = temp;
                }
            }

            Console.Write(arr[i]+",");
        }
             Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Hello there this kind of sorting is called `Bubble Sort`. Basically each element in the array is one bye one compared with the next elements if the element is bigger then it is replaced with the next element. Just like a bubble bigger elements go to the right end of the array :)

Comment: There are a few animations on the YouTube for the Bubble Sort. For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9I2oOAr2okY

Answer (score 1):

This is a bubble sort. Herein you sort the array in ascending order. You do this by comparing the index element with all the other elements in the array and ensuring that the index element in the smallest one.

Suppose the array has only 4 elements :-

```
9,1,6,3
```

Iteration 1 will be :-

1. Send Index element as 9
2. Compare index element(9) with 2nd element(1)
3. Swap Index element(9) and 2nd element(1) as 2nd element is smaller
4. New array is 1,9,6,3
5. Compare index element(1) with 3rd element(6)
6. Do nothing
7. Compare index element(1) with 4th element(3)
8. Do nothing
9. Array is 1,9,6,3

Iteration 2 will be :-

1. Set Index element as 9
2. Compare index element(9) with 3rd element(6)
3. Swap Index element(9) and 3rd element(6) as 3rd element is smaller
4. New array is 1,6,9,3
5. Compare index element(6) with 4th element(3)
6. Swap Index element(9) and 4th element(6) as 4th element is smaller
7. Array is 1,3,9,6

Iteration 3 will be :-

1. Set Index element as 9
2. Compare index element(9) with 4th element(6)
3. Swap Index element(9) and 4th element(6) as 4th element is smaller
4. New array is 1,3,6,9

Now the array is sorted.

Comment: I can understand but in iteration 1 how it is comparing again with third element. I cannot get how that loop is running

Comment: For iteration 1, i = 0, j= 1 and arr.length = 4. Therefore after setting the index values as arr[0], it runs the inner for loop, comparing the arr[0] values with arr[1],arr[2] and arr[3].